# Pi Camera + openCV connection issues with V4l2 already installed?

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I am using openCV to access the camera- and for some reason it will not connect to the pi camera, Can anyone see any reason why that may be?

my code to test camera is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>
#include "move.h"
#include "init.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "distance.h"
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <../include/libv4l2.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
using namespace cv;


void TestCamera(){

Mat initframe,blurr,B_W,edges;
//Mat image;
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,500);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,500);


 if (cap.isOpened()){


for(;;)
{
    cap.read(initframe);
    if (initframe.empty()){ printf("error frame empty/n");  break;}

imshow("Live Stream",initframe);        //normal bgr output

cvtColor(initframe,B_W,CV_BGR2GRAY);//b&W stream
imshow("greyscale",B_W);

GaussianBlur(B_W,blurr,Size(9,9),1.5,1.5);//blur applied so edge detction is smoother (less hard edges)
imshow("blurr",blurr);

Canny(blurr,edges,0,30,3);//edge detection
imshow("edges",edges);



if(waitKey(30)>= 0) break;
}
}else printf("error! unable to use camera\n");

}
```

and the build command is:

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include $(pkg-config opencv --libs) $(pkg-config opencv --cflags) -o "SdCar" "SdCar.cpp" -lwiringPi -lpigpio -lv4l2 (in directory: /home/pi/selfdrivingcar-17)
```

I cant figure out why it builds but whenever the camera should run it says "error!unable to open camera" which is the error associated with cap.IsOpened() function.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you loaded the broadcom v4l2 module? `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` Or add it to `/etc/modules` so it loads after reboot.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I am unsure wether my #include is correct but have tried changing things round and still no luck

Comment: It's nothing to do with `#include` which is for your compiler, rather it is a kernel module.

Comment: but surely if the #include is not pointing to the file correctly it will not find it and thus will not connect correctly?@MarkSetchell

Comment: The compiler just makes a program - it can make a program regardless of whether you even have a camera, or a raspberry pi. The kernel module allows the kernel to talk to the camera and both it, and the camera must be installed if the program is to run. Please just run the `sudo modprobe ...` command I suggested.

Comment: Mark, As i mentioned I have already done that, I have fixed the error now by changing it from #include <../include/libv4l2.h> to #include <libv4l2.h>

Comment: So everything is working now?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, Now trying to implement the Neural Net for image classification